# Dont use on cascade persist if entity has an id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

It is possible in hibernate that If I have a relationship between A and B where A is the owner of the dependency only do the on cascade persist if B dont has id?. I have the problem that when A does not exist and B neither everything it´s ok with the persist. The same situation when A exist and B as well and we do the merge. BUT the problem arrive when A does not exist but B do, then A try to persist B and because B is already persisted IK receive the exception.
So my current implementation is remove the persist cascade due of this user case and persist B previous persist A in two different transactions. But I was wondering if something in the wonderful world of hibernate exist. Like Apply on cascade persist if B does not has id.

Ant thoughts?

Comment: good to know im not the only one confused by so many cascade types ; ) I would try to use SAVE_UPDATE

Comment: Add some code snippet to get better help. Add error/stacktrace, if any.